# Valgrind: executable is not for this architecture

Tags: linux, valgrind, memory-overhead

I am trying to find memory overhead of my cpp executables generated for x86 and RISC architecture using Valgrind. I have done valgrind successfully for x86 executable, But When I try for RISC architecture on Linux machine it shows the error as shown in the figure. The same issue occurred with gprof as well But I sloved it using qemu user mode. And even tried to execute the executable using qemu first and then tried to do valgrind as shown in figure but not working. What I can do to solve this or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you write "Linux machine": You you mean the x86 Linux machine or a second Linux machine that has a RISC (do you mean "RISC V"?) CPU?

Comment: @MartinRosenau I mean x86 Linux machine. There is no second Linux machine. And I mean RISC V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valgrind has no support for RISC V, and I'm not aware of anyone in the Valgrind community working on it. The currently supported architectures are x86/amd64, mips, nanomips, arm, POWER, s390, with mips and arm having 32 and 64bit versions.

For the moment you will need to find and use other tools.